# Processing an array by sub arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose we have an array of variable length, and I want to process it by chunks that are of a maximum length of 100, and do it in the minimum number of chunks. So for an array of length 241, it would be 3 sub arrays of sizes 41, 100, 100 (or 100, 100, 41).

```
curr_len = arr.length;
offset = curr_len%100;
doSomethingWithSubArray(arr.slice(offset))

for(j = offset; j <= curr_len; j = j+100){
    doSomethingWithSubArray(arr.slice(j,j+100))
}
```

I'm sure there are more elegant ways of doing this, possibly without the special case before the for loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd expect the last chunk to be of smaller size. The code then would be:

```
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=100)
    doSomethingWithSubArray(arr.slice(i, 100));
```

This is exactly what my splitBy function does:

```
Array.prototype.splitBy = function(n) {
/* get: number of items per array
return: array of n-sized arrays with the items (last array may contain less then n) */
    for (var r=[], i=0; i<this.length; i+=n)
        r.push(this.slice(i, i+n));
    return r;
}
```

Then write only:

```
arr.splitBy(100).forEach(doSomethingWithSubArray);
```

Comment: Of course. For some reason, my brain was avoiding this to avoid an IndexOutOfRange. I guess javascript is wonderful.

Comment: my solution is consice better yours how about this?

Answer (score 1):

use chunk function~

```
function chunk(a, s){
    for(var x, i = 0, c = -1, l = a.length, n = []; i < l; i++)
        (x = i % s) ? n[c][x] = a[i] : n[++c] = [a[i]];
    return n;
}

console.log(chunk([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

it's functional style recursive solutions.
no var, no loop, no count, because it's more cleary

```
var chunk = function(arr, n){
    if (arr.length == 0) return [];
    var head = arr.slice(0, n), rest = arr.slice(n);

    return [head].concat( chunk(rest, n) );
};

console.log(chunk([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 3));​
```

Comment: No "var" is not really true :-) However, most people understand loops easier than recursive calls - and they're faster, too.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) looks like this:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];

var splitArrays = array.reduce(function(arr, cur, i) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) arr.push([]);
    arr[i / 3 | 0].push(cur);
    return arr;
}, []);
//splitArrays looks like:
//[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11]]
```

More generic function

```
function splitArray(array, num) {
    return array.reduce(function(arr, cur, i) {
        if (i % num === 0) arr.push([]);
        arr[i / num | 0].push(cur);
        return arr;
    }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `doSomethingWithSubArray` function accept a starting index and return a next unprocessed index or `null` if there's no more work. Put this "iterator" in a `while` loop. Do rest of work that you want to do between chunks (update UI?) right after calling this "iterator" in a `while` condition.